# QGIS graphical modeler and raster calculator

Tags: qgis, raster-calculator, qgis-modeler

I'm making a graphical modeler that creates me a kind of DSM, like that:

[image]

1. I create a DEM for my extent (I have the DEM for my whole country).
2. I have the Lidar for the height of the forest and I extract it for
   my extent.
3. I also have a polygon that I rasterized. It is where the
   forest should be cut off (1/0 meaning yes/no).

As you can see, everything works fine. I have my raster layers (same CRS, same resolution, same extent).

[image]

Now, I want to do this in raster calculator:

[image]

So in words, it means if the forest is cut (No forest =1) then the value is DEM, and if the forest is not cut then the value is DEM+Lidar forest.

The problem is, I always have this error:

[image]

```
Impossible to load the source layer for INPUT_A: invalid value

Error during raster calculator execution
```

I use QGIS 3.22

But as you can see, my modeler produises the 3 rasters (temporary files) without any problem:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: In error message, `INPUT_A` is empty.  Maybe nothing returns from "No Forest" tool.

Comment: No, it is not that, cause as you can see the "No Forest" tool produces me a raster layer as expected.

Answer (score 0):

It may be that the "No Forest" layer needs to be explicitly mentioned as a dependency in the Raster Calculator. This would make sure that "No Forest" gets created *before* the Raster Calculator runs.

(Your screenshot of the Raster Calculator cut off the Dependencies field, so I can't tell if it was already set.)

One would think that listing the "No Forest" layer in the algorithm inputs would create an implicit dependency...after all, the line from "No Forest" to the raster calculator appears in the model.  But maybe a bug prevents the implicit dependency here.

I have run into situations where making an explicit dependency clears up a problem, even though it seems like it would not be necessary.

Answer (score 0):

I have had times when referencing a temporary (aka "memory") raster layer causes problems in the modeler.  Try specifying a file on disk for the "No Forest" output when you run the model.  That may help the raster calculator find the missing input.